# Problem with defining a basis for a transformation to act on in a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Problem: Suppose $W$ is finite dimensional and $T_1,T_2 \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$.Prove that null$T_1$=null$T_2$ if and only if there exists an invertible linear operator $S \in \mathcal{L}(W)$ such that $T_1=ST_2$

I looked at an answer to this proof. They started it by assuming range$T_2$ is finite dimensional. They let $w_1,...,w_m$ be a basis for this range. Thus there exists $v_1,...,v_m$ such that $T_2(v_i)=w_i$ for $i \in \{1,...,m\}$ Thus the linear map is defined by $T_2(a_1v_1+\ldots +a_mv_m)=a_1w_1+\dots +a_mw_m$

My question here is how can we define this linear map? How do we know that $v_1,...v_m$ form a basis for $V$?

What if there are basis vectors in $V$ in the null space of $T$ that get mapped to zero such that the dimension of V is greater than m?

Comment: It can be shown that the $\{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$ are linearly independent. Also, are you assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional? and what is $T$ in this question?

Comment: No the problem does not say $V$ is finite dimensional Even if $v_1,...,v_m$ are linearly independent isn't it true we can only define this map if $v_1,...v_m$ is a basis of $V$?

Comment: yes, that's right. what we can do is extend this basis to be a basis of $V$ (this is possible even in infinite dimensions I believe if you assume the axiom of choice) but I don't see how this $T$ is helpful. Is the $T$ supposed to somehow be $S$? (I still haven't figured out this problem yet lol so I can't see the idea yet)

Comment: We don't know that $v_1,\dots,v_m$ forms a basis for $V$, but we do know that it can be *extended* to a basis $v_1,\dots,v_m,v_{m+1},\dots$.  Alternatively we know that there exists a complementary subspace to the span of $v_1,\dots,v_m$ within $V$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Does this mean we take $T(v_i)=0$ for $i=m+1,...$?

Comment: Yes, if we want to say what $T_2$ does on all of $V$.

Comment: I don't see a difference here between $T$ and $T_2$ unless we specify something like "$T$ is only defined on its domain which is the span of $v_1,\dots,v_m$"

Comment: My bad I made an error

Comment: I think you answered my question here. I wanted to know why a transformation was defined on vectors that were not basis vectors. The answer was that the linearly independent set can be extended to a basis. That's all I needed to know. The rest of the solution I read was long and complicated

Comment: Here is a link to the solution https://linearalgebras.com/3d.html (#4)

Comment: Let's say we extend $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ to a basis $B$ for $V$. It is not necessarily true that $T_2(v)=0$ for basis vectors $v\in B-\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$. We could have $T_2(v)=2\cdot w_1+3\cdot w_2$ for all $v\in B-\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard so you mean if we map vectors $v \in B- \{v_1,...,v_m\}$ to linear combinations of vectors in $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ we would get the same result?Instead of mapping all to zero?

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard also when extending a set of linearly independent vectors to a basis then defining maps on each basis vector, in the case above couldn't we always define $T(v_i)=0$ for $v_i \in B-\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ even though we don't have to, to make the transformation convenient?

Comment: @68e1515 No, I did not say that. We know that $T_2(v_i)=w_i$, and we have a basis $B$ for $V$ that includes $v_1,\ldots,v_m$. We do not know where $T_2$ sends the other basis vectors. For all we know, it may be the case that $T_2(v)=2\cdot w_1+3\cdot w_2$ for $v\in B-\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$. We don't know what $T_2(v)$ is for any $v\in B$, except $v_1,\ldots,v_m$.

Comment: @68e1515 I was trying to be helpful. And I was not trying to condescend to anyone. Earlier in the comments it was suggested that we extend $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ to a basis for $V$. This basis was written as a (possibly trans-finite) sequence $v_1,\ldots,v_m,v_{m+1},\dots$. You had asked if this implied that $T(v_{m+1})=T(v_{m+2})=\ldots=0$. I thought it would be helpful to point out that is not necessarily true that $T(v_{m+1})=T(v_{m+2})=\ldots=0$.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard What's making me confused is I feel like in this problem we are defining a map on the basis vectors for $V$ such that $T_2(v_i)=w_i$ for all $i \in \{1,...,m\}$ and we can do so by mapping all the other $v_i$'s to zero I thought we had more freedom in defining our maps than you suggest.

Comment: I think the way we got the $w_i$'s and $v_i$'s was like this: we start with the fact that the image of $T_2$ is finite-dimensional. This is true because the image is a subspace of $W$, which is finite-dimensional. So we can pick a basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ for the image of $T_2$. Since each $w_i$ is in the image of $T_2$, each $w_i=T_2(v_i)$ for some $v_i\in V$. Next we can show that the $v_i$'s are linearly independent, using the fact that the $w_i$'s are linearly independent. Hence, we can extend $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ to a basis for $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I've posted a solution to the original problem in your post. I've broken down the proof into a series of exercises. I've done this in order to highlight the main ideas, and so that I wouldn't bore you with details that you are already comfortable with. If it would be helpful to have solutions to any of these exercises, then let me know. I'll be happy to help.

The original problem was:

**Problem:** Suppose $W$ is finite dimensional and $T_1,T_2\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Prove that $\text{null }T_1=\text{null }T_2$ if and only if there exists an invertible linear operator $S\in\mathcal{L}(W)$ such that $T_1=ST_2$.

**Solution, Part 1:** First suppose we have an invertible $S\in\mathcal{L}(W)$ with $T_1=ST_2$. Our goal is to show that $\text{null }T_1=\text{null }T_2$.

**Exercise 1:** Prove that $\text{null }T_1=\text{null }T_2$, given that $T_1=ST_2$ for some invertible $S\in\mathcal{L}(W)$. $\square$

**Part 2:** Suppose that $\text{null }T_1=\text{null }T_2$. Our goal is to show that there is an invertible $S\in\mathcal{L}(W)$, with $T_1=ST_2$.

Note that the image of $T_2$ is finite-dimensional, since it is a subspace of $W$, which is finite-dimensional. Let $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ be a basis for the image of $T_2$. For each $w_i$, pick a $v_i\in V$ with $T_2(v_i)=w_i$.

**Exercise 2:** Show that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ is linearly independent.

Let $V_1=\text{null }T_1=\text{null }T_2$, and let $V_2=\text{span }\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$.

**Exercise 3:** Show that $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$.

For $1\le i\le m$, let $u_i=T_1(v_i)$.

**Exercise 4:** Show that $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ is linearly independent. You may find it helpful to use the fact that $V_1\cap V_2=\{0\}$.

Since $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ is linearly independent, it can be extended to a basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m,\ldots,w_n\}$ for $W$. And since $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ is linearly independent, it can be extended to a basis $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m,\ldots,u_n\}$ for $W$. Let $S:W\to W$ be the unique linear transformation that sends $w_i\mapsto u_i$ for $1\le i\le n$. Then $S\in\mathcal{L}(W)$, and $S$ is invertible since it sends a basis to a basis. All that remains is to show that $T_1=ST_2$.

**Exercise 5:** Show that $V_1+V_2=V$. In other words, show that for every $x\in V$ there exist $y\in V_1$, $z\in V_2$ such that $x=y+z$.

**Exercise 6:** Show that $T_1=ST_2$. You may find it helpful to use the fact that $V_1+V_2=V$. $\square$

**Comment:** The fact that $W$ is finite-dimensional simplified notation in **Part 2**, but this assumption is not necessary in either part of the proof.